# if at t0, and then at t1 I add to the DOM an img tag with the exact same url, will the browser make two requests?

Tags: javascript, browser, browser-cache, prefetch

I'm sure this is dependent on browsers.

Say for example that the initial html response includes `<img id="img1" src="/pic.jpg"/>` as well as `<script src="/script.js"/>`.

And assume there's not many other separate resources so the browser can parallelize these requests.

So consider `t0` to be `DOMContentLoaded`.  The browser should initiate requests for both `pic.jpg` and `script.js`.

Say that as soon as `script.js` loads and begins executing, it adds to another place in the dom `<img id="img2" src="/pic.jpg"/>`.  Consider this `t1`.

If at `t1`, the image that began loading at `t0` had already completed loading, then I would think the browser would use its cache to display `id="img2"` since they're the same URL.

But what if at `t1`, the first instance of the `img` hadn't yet completed?

Would the browser initiate a second, parallel, completely redundant request, or would it be smart enough to know to just wait on the `t0` request for *both* instances?

Thanks

Comment: Ultimately it's up to the browser implementor; you certainly can't rely on it *not* making two requests.

Comment: have you looked at the network section of the browsers dev tools while loading your example

Comment: @chiliNUT, I have, but I was wondering if anyone might have experience/knowledge about this scenario in multiple browsers.